# Download code uploaded to projectName.meteor.com

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to download the code for the `projectName` app that I uploaded to `projectName.meteor.com`?

Is there a meteor command line interface that will accomplish this?

Comment: Hmm, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible through any meteor tools.

You can get the client side code by reading out the javascript files over from projectName.meteor.com. The files will be concatenated and minified so they will be far from the original albeit a bit helpful if you can rebeautify them.

For the server side code you'll have to contact the guys who run meteor.com and hopefully they can help you out with that. Keep in mind most of your code will be minified and may not be like the original.

Comment: That is what I was doing - thanks for confirming. This would be great for disaster recovery if local dev copies get corrupted we could pull from working project in production and start over.